# h.264 data packets to 'realtime' playback/preview using Apple's VideoToolbox

Tags: avfoundation, osx-mavericks, video-capture, decoding, compression

From the Apple Documentation, the Quicktime framework is deprecated in OSX 10.9 in favor of AVFoundations and AVKit.  For reasons I am not sure of, most of the documentation neglects to mention that some of the Quicktime framework replacement functionality is covered by a Framework called VideoToolbox. That replacement functionality includes decoding and decompressing among others.

I would like to decode and decompress h.264 encoded video data packets (NAL packets, TS packet, ect…), put them in a pixel buffer and then use Core Video and OpenGL to display the video as it comes in.

I am getting the video data packets from and encoding box via usb. This box does not show up when I run `[AVCaptureDevice devices]`. So I can not use most of AVFoundation (to my knowledge) to interface directly with the box. However, there is an api that comes with the box, that gives me access the video data packet files. I can write them to disk and create a video that can be played by quicktime. But doing a realtime playback is the issue. Thus the question of decoding, decompression, and creating a pixel buffer so I can use Core Video and OpenGL.

I think if I can create a pixel buffer I may be able to use `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` and figure out some way to get that into a `AVCaptureSession`. If I can do that, I should be able forgo using OpenGL and use the tools afforded me in AVFoundations and AVKit.

Also, from my reading of the AVFoundations documentation, every time they talk about streams of video/audio data, they are talking about one of two things; either a streams coming from a AVCaptureDevice or processing a stream from HTTP Live Stream. Like I said before, the box that produces the video data packets does not show up as a `AVCaptureDevice`. And, I would rather not build/implement a HTTP Live Streaming server if I do not need to. (Hopefully, I do not need to although I saw online some people did.)

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it has been a while, but I finally figure out how to use VideoToolbox correctly with a raw uncompressed and encoded data stream.

Basically, I had to familiarize myself with the H264 specifications and got much help from this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884827/possible-locations-for-sequence-picture-parameter-sets-for-h-264-stream#answer-24890903).

Here are the steps

1. Make sure you get your Sequence Parameter Set (SPS) and Picture
   Parameter Set (PPS) before you start processing any data.
2. Use the SPS and PPS to get the necessary data to create an avcc atom
   header.  See post I linked to above.
3. Save the avcc atom header in NSData.
4. Create a CMVideoFormatDescription with avcc atom and configured
   extentions.  See CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate documentation.
5. Set up VTDecompressionOutputCallbackRecord
6. Set pixelBufferAttributes that will be used in
   VTDecompressionSessionCreate.
7. Create a CMBlockBuffer from the data that was not used in creating
   CMVideoFormatDescription.  See CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock.
   Basically, you want to make sure you are adding you raw nal packets
   that are not SPS or PPS. You may need to add the size of
   the current nal packet + 4, for everything to work right. Again
   refer to link above.
8. Create CMBlockBuffer
9. Create CMSampleBuffer
10. Use CMSampleBuffer in VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame to do
    the decoding.
11. Run VTDecompressionSessionWaitForAsynchronousFrames after VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame.  I noticed if I did not run VTDecompressionSessionWaitForAsynchronousFrames, my display output was jittery.
12. What ever functionality you defined for the function used in
    VTDecompressionOutputCallbackRecord will get called.  Presently, I
    am passing a CVPixelBufferRef to OpenGL to write the video to the
    screen.  Maybe at some point I will try to use AVFoundations to
    write to the screen.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: If you have an apple developer account, you can check out [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/959077#959077)